# Bounded $r$- variation function with a dense set of local maximum values

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

This is a sharpening of the following problem: [$C^1$ function with a dense set of maximum values](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392347/c1-function-with-a-dense-set-of-maximum-values).

**Problem set up:**

Let $f \colon [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ be a function on the unit interval. We say $y \in \mathbb R$ is a local maximum value of $f$ if $y = f(x)$ for some strict local maximum $x$ of $f$.

> **Question:** Let $r > 1$. Does there exist a function $f$ on the unit interval of bounded $r$-variation such that the set of local maximum values of $f$ is dense in some (nontrivial) open interval $(a, \, b)$?

**Remarks:**

Note that a $C^0$ example is provided by a Brownian motion sample path, since a Brownian motion almost surely achieves a strict maximum in every interval. In the above problem, it is shown that a $C^1$ function with the above properties cannot exist, and I believe neither can a bounded variation one.

Thus an interesting question to ask is of bounded $r$-variation. The case $r = 1$ is impossible, and $r > 2$ is given by Brownian motion. For which $r$ precisely can this phenomenon occur?

Comment: Note that Brownian paths have infinite $2$-variation with probability one.

Comment: Oh wow you’re right. That’s subtle. I should say higher than 2 then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are happy with probabilistic constructions, fractional Brownian motion $X_t^H$ gives an answer. If it's Hurst parameter is $H \in (0, 1)$, then the paths of $X_t^H$ have infinite $1/H$-variation with probability one, and hence they necessarily attain local maxima in a dense set of $t$, just as the usual Brownian motion. On the other hand, the $r$-variation of $X_t^H$ is finite with probability one for every $r > 1/H$, and of course such $r$ can be arbitrarily close to $1$ if one chooses $H$ appropriately.

A sample reference for the above is:

- Pratelli M. (2011) *A Remark on the $1/H$-Variation of the Fractional Brownian Motion*. In: Donati-Martin C., Lejay A., Rouault A. (eds) *Séminaire de Probabilités XLIII*. Lecture Notes in Mathematics, vol 2006. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg. [DOI:10.1007/978-3-642-15217-7_8](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-15217-7_8)

Answer (score 4):

The Takagi function [1], [2] has finite r-variation for all $r>1$. The proof [1] that it is nowhere differentiable also shows that the locations of local maxima are dense in an interval and so are their values.

[1] Takagi, Teiji (1901), "A Simple Example of the Continuous Function without Derivative", Proc. Phys.-Math. Soc. Jpn., 1: 176–177

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blancmange_curve

Comment: In fact *any* function that has infinite total variation on every interval necessarily has local maxima on a dense subset of the domain.

Answer (score 1):

I just realised that there is a function of bounded variation — in fact, even a Lipschitz one — that attains local maxima on a dense subset of its domain.

The construction is in fact quite simple. We need a set $A$ such that for every interval $(a, b)$, both $(a, b) \cap A$ and $(a, b) \setminus A$ have positive Lebesgue measure. Then
\[ f(x) = \int_0^x (2 \cdot \mathbb 1_A(s) - 1) ds \]
is clearly a Lipschitz function. Furthermore, for every interval $(a, b)$ there are $x_1 \in (a, \tfrac{a+b}{2})$ and $x_2 \in (\tfrac{a+b}{2}, b)$ such that $f'(x_1) = 1$ and $f'(x_2) = -1$ (indeed: $f'(x) = 1$ for almost all $x \in A$, and $f'(x) = -1$ for almost all $x \notin A$), and therefore $f$ attains a local maximum in $(a, b)$, somewhere between $x_1$ and $x_2$.

The set $A$ can be constructed as follows: let $q_n$ be a sequence of all rationals in $(0, 1)$, let $A_0 = \varnothing$, and define
\[ A_{n+1} = \bigl(A_n \cup (q_n, q_n + \tfrac{1}{3^n})\bigr) \setminus (q_n - \tfrac{1}{3^n}, q_n) . \]
Then $A_{n+1}$ and $A_n$ differ on a set of measure at most $\tfrac{2}{3^n}$, and since this sequence is summable, the limiting set $A = \lim_{n \to \infty} A_n$ is well-defined up to a null set. Finally, it is easy to show that for $k > n$ the sets $(q_n, q_n + \tfrac{1}{3^n}) \cap A_k$ and $(q_n - \tfrac{1}{3^n}, q_n) \setminus A_k$ have measure at least
\[ \tfrac{1}{3^n} - \tfrac{1}{3^{n+1}} - \tfrac{1}{3^{n+1}} - \ldots - \tfrac{1}{3^{k-1}} > \tfrac{1}{2 \cdot 3^n} \]
and consequently both $(q_n, q_n + \tfrac{1}{3^n}) \cap A$ and $(q_n - \tfrac{1}{3^n}, q_n) \setminus A$ have positive measure (at least $\tfrac{1}{2 \cdot 3^n}$). Since every interval $(a, b)$ contains $(q_n - \tfrac{1}{3^n}, q_n + \tfrac{1}{3^n})$ for some $n$, we conclude that $(a, b) \cap A$ and $(a, b) \setminus A$ both have positive measure.

Comment: It is surprising to me that you can get a bounded variation one! The proof I had in mind was to show by contradiction a bounded variation function could not exist by zigzagging between the dense set of maximum values, but apparently this wouldn’t be enough to get unbounded variation because you can hit the values in an almost monotone manner as in your construction.

Comment: Very nice solve as usual @Mateusz Kwasnicki